# Line breaks into database

Tags: php, html, text

I am making a posts area for readers, my problem is that when a user inserts a new post it is saved into the database in this form:

```
Some say the world will end in fire,<br /> Some say in ice.<br /> From what I’ve tasted of desire<br /> I hold with those who favor fire.<br /> But if it had to perish twice,<br /> I think I know enough of hate<br /> To say that for destruction ice<br /> Is also great<br /> And would suffice.
```

I want it to be saved like this:

```
 Some say the world will end in fire,<br />
 Some say in ice.<br />
 From what I’ve tasted of desire<br />
 I hold with those who favor fire.<br />
 But if it had to perish twice,<br />
 I think I know enough of hate<br />
 To say that for destruction ice<br />
 Is also great<br />
 And would suffice.
```

I want it to make "enter" after each line break with keeping the tag (for editing issues)

Here are my current posting text parameters before inserting to database

```
$body = strip_tags($body);
$body = mysqli_real_escape_string($this->con, $body); 
$body = str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $body);
$body = nl2br($body);
```

Comment: There is no any \r\n or \n in the first post form, try to change `str_replace('\r\n', "\n", $body);` with `str_replace('<br />', "<br />\n", $body);`. Let me know if it's work

Comment: What is the point of what you want? It's just a visual representation. It does not affect anything other than viewing the column in a db manager. If you are using a rich text editor, it should work fine with `<br/>`s

Answer (score 0):

I think the the text you are saving is not containing any \r\n, that's why it's getting saved in a single line. and then you are trying to search and replace the same thing.
Try to search 
 and then append \n for new line like this:

```
str_replace('<br />', "<br />\n", $body);
```

I hope this work.

Comment: your way works only after the data is saved in database, but I want it to work when submiting a post for the 1st time, when submiting the post for the 1st time it doesn`t have any line break tags..

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by automatically calling the body function from the database after submitting the post and then applying `str_replace` and `nl2br` as following:

```
$returned_ip = mysqli_insert_id($this->con);
$body= str_replace("<br />","\n" , $body); 
$body= nl2br($body);
$update_query = mysqli_query($this->con, "UPDATE poems SET poem_body='$body' WHERE ip='$returned_ip'");
```